# ghci haskell programming in linux

Tags: linux, haskell, ghci, haskell-platform, winghci

i'm trying to install GHCi version 8.0.2 on linux ubunto 14.10 i'm using a virtual machine vmware 12.5  thought i followed the steps of installation of the site of haskell platform but i have always the same error:

hp@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install haskell-platform

[sudo] password for hp:

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package haskell-platform

Is there any solution? what should i do ??

Comment: Maybe you should migrate this to AskUbuntu. The haskell-platform is present on [several](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=haskell-platform&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) ubuntu versions. Ubuntu 14 is a bit oldish and only has GHC 7.6.3.

Comment: If you really need 8.0.2, install zesty, or (probably easier) install it manually from the ghc website.

Comment: 8.0.2? That's not even in Ubuntu 16.10. @chi [hvr packages](https://www.haskell.org/downloads/linux) are usually good enough to get started. (The PPA includes 8.0.2 as well as the 8.2 "preview")

Comment: Thank you very much it's probably the version that cause the problem so  i will try with GHC 7.6.3 because i tried hvr packages and  it doesn't work too.